# Nav2009 web service through android?

Tags: android, web-services, navision

Im trying to access nav 2009 web service from android client.

I tried `ksoap2` library and `jcifs` library. `ksoap2` gives `illegalargumentexception` at `transport.call` and `jcifs` gives `authentication error`.

Is there any other way to access nav web service?

JCIFS:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            String webserviceIP = "-------------"; // IP of the server.
            String username = "---------"; // Domain username
            String password ="--------"; // Domain password
            String deviceIP="" ;
            String domainName = "-----"; // Domain name


            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory());

            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(webserviceIP, -1), new NTCredentials(username, password, deviceIP, domainName));

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
            httpGet.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);

            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                String responseXML = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        return null;

    }
```

ksoap2:

```
                     SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);

                request.addProperty("No", arg0[0]);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet=true;

                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                 HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
             try {
                transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             //SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

Comment: I'm not keen in android. Check that it is proper authentication method set in web service settings `<add key="WebServicesUseNTLMAuthentication" value="true"></add>`/ This may be issue with `authentication error`.

Comment: As for `illegal argument` it may mean corrupted XML (try to wipe indentation, if its presents, from XML) or missing SOAPAction header (i think its mandatory for Nav WS).

Comment: For illegalargumentexception @Mak the transport.call method passes size<=0 to bufferedinputstream class.That means the stream the transport class gets is also empty which i think also because of authentication error.

Comment: Thank you @MakSim .I checked that authentication element in config fle it was false .Changed it to true.The web service now connects through jcifs but getting the same error in ksoap2.I should add authentication to that transport.call.

Comment: Is it returning HTTP 500 error? That means you have incorrect SOAP request. In most cases Nav will newer tell you what is wrong. Try get whats in `envelope` variable and try to send it to WS using other tools like SOAPui (only night build of SOAPui works well with Nav) or just post it here.

Comment: No @MakSim It is not returning any error.There is something wrong with the request generated by the ksoap2 lib.I took the requestdump in logcat.It looks this                  <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header /><v:Body>
<n0:Read id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/customer">
<No i:type="d:string">CO0001</No>
</n0:Read>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>

Comment: @MakSim I tried the above request in ws studio it returned authentication error.But ws studio works well with this request <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <Read xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/customer">
      <No>CO0001</No>
    </Read>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: @MakSim Im thinking of creating an another service in that machine with JSON request and response which will communicate with nav webservice by SOAP.So that it will reduce the network load in my mobile device,Hope this works.

Comment: creating another service is an option but you will face additional troubles. You will have to deal with connection pulling, concurrency and throttling which already implemented in Nav WS. Also you will probably have to impersonate user in some way.

Comment: Translation from JSON to valid XML for Nav is not so simple as well

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see your XML is not valid. It contains ";" between tags for example. Try to generate proper XML.

Here is what you can try:

1. Run SOAPui (SNAPSHOT build supports NTLM auth)
2. Consume Nav WS (feed the WSDL's URL to SOAPui)
3. Generate sample XML request (there is a command for that)
4. Remove unprintable characters at the end of each line. Those added by app, for me it looks like a bug and Nav don't like them as well.
5. Remove any characters between `<v:Header />` and `<v:Body>` including CR. Looks like there is a bug in Nav WS.
6. Insert parameters to request.
7. Run request.

If there will be errors fix them and make request work. After you have working XML request force any of your libs to generate same request.